# SVN : Status files D while files does not exist anymore from local directory nor from repository

Tags: svn

Severals files have been deleted from the local directory.
The same files no longer exist from the the repository.

But the command svn status always list the files with D status. Ho can I clean that ?

Answer (score 2):

Your working copy is out of date, as far as it looks like. The file has been already removed in the repository but your working copy has this file as scheduled for deletion. As far as I guess, when you attempt to commit, you'll get an error like "your working copy is out of date, run `svn update` to update it".

Read [SVNBook | Review Your Changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine).